# C++, Error, Native' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005)

Tags: c++

I wrote a programe in C++ but in debugging I encountered a problem, I'll be glad if you can help me in this Code,The Source of the code and the error has been declaired in the following :

The error is:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x011019d6 in 33.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdcd.
```

The Code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 
const int maxCard =100;
//enum Boll {false, true};

class Contact 
{

public:
    Contact (const char *name, const char *address, const char *tell);
    //~ Contact(void);
    const char* Name (void)  const {return name;}
    const char* Address (void) const {return address;}
    const char* Tell (void) const {return tell;}
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, Contact&);
private:
    char *name;
    char *address;
    char *tell;
};
class ContactDir 
{
public:
    ContactDir(const int maxSize);
    //~ContactDir(void);
    void Insert(const Contact &);
    void Delete(const char *name);
    Contact* Find(const char *name);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream&, ContactDir&);
private: 
    int Lookup (const char *name);
    Contact **contacts;
    int dirSize;
    int maxSize;
};
Contact::Contact(const char *name, const char *address, const char *tell)
{
    Contact::name= new char [strlen(name)+1];
    Contact::address= new char [strlen(address)+1];
    Contact::tell= new char [strlen(tell)+1];
    strcpy(Contact::name, name);
    strcpy(Contact::address, address);
    strcpy(Contact::tell,tell);
}
/*Contact::~Contact (void)
{
    delete name;
    delete address;
    delete tell;
}*/
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, Contact &c)
{
    os<<"("<<c.name<<","<<c.address<<","<<c.tell<< ")";
    return os;
}
ContactDir::ContactDir (const int max)
{
    typedef Contact *ContactPtr;
    dirSize=0;
    maxSize=max;
    contacts= new ContactPtr[maxSize];
};
/*ContactDir::~ContactDir (void)
{
    for(register int i=0; i<dirSize; ++i)
        delete contacts[i];
    delete []contacts;
}*/
void ContactDir::Insert (const Contact& c)
{
    if (dirSize<maxSize)
    { 
        int idx= Lookup(c.Name());
        if(idx>0 &&strcmp(c.Name(), contacts[idx]->Name())==0)
        { 
            delete contacts [idx];
        }
        else 
        {
            for (register int i=dirSize; i>idx; --i)
                contacts[i]=contacts[i-1];
            ++dirSize;
        }
        contacts[idx]=new Contact (c.Name(),c.Address(),c.Tell());
    }
}
void ContactDir::Delete (const char *name)
{
    int idx=Lookup(name);
    if(idx<dirSize)
    {
        delete contacts[idx];
        --dirSize;
        for (register int i=idx; i<dirSize; i++)
            contacts[i]=contacts[i+1];
    }
}
Contact *ContactDir::Find (const char *name)
{
    int idx= Lookup (name);
    return (idx< dirSize && strcmp (contacts[idx]->Name(), name)==0)? contacts[idx]:0;
}
int ContactDir:: Lookup (const char *name)
{
    for (register int i=0; i<dirSize; ++i)
        if (strcmp (contacts[i]->Name(), name)==0)
            return i;
    return dirSize;
}

ostream &operator << (ostream &os, ContactDir &c)
{
    for (register int i=0; i<c.dirSize; ++i)
        os<< *(c.contacts[i]) << '\n';
    return os;
}

int main (void)
{
    ContactDir dir (10);
    dir.Insert(Contact ("JACK","NORWAY", "999999"));
    dir.Insert(Contact ("JIMMY","FRANCE", "313131"));
    cout<<dir;

}
```

Comment: Why is `const char *` everywhere when `std::string` exists?

Comment: You should run the program in a debugger, it will tell you where the access violation occurs. (In which line of the source code)

Comment: Every time there's a max-element-count upon an uncertain number of elements, the design is foul. Why don't you use one of the standard containers?

Comment: also: your code is not exception-safe and utterly leaks memory. Again, don't code C, prefer to code C++ (std::(string|vector|list)).

Comment: why does operator<< have to be a friend?

Comment: This may be a homework.  Not that I'm defending the use of the ol' C-strings, and I don't agree with it, but some professors decide it's more challenging.

Comment: @jonsca: then the student has to reinvent the string class, instead of messing with pointers everywhere :)

Comment: @vines True.  Probably beyond some of those students, which is why the std::string would be friendlier.

Comment: Guys, cut the guy some slack... we all started somewhere. This could obviously be done better, but being exception-safe is probably way beyond the scope of the task. It's not thread-safe either. So what? NAIEM, correct me if I'm wrong, but this is not going to production, is it?...

Comment: @Eran: **Especially** you are "just starting C++" it is imperative that you **not** start by using `char *` everywhere. This cannot be stressed enough. You would get *more* slack if you were a 50-year old C programmer who wants to explore a new language. (Apologies to the OP in that event.)

Comment: @Kerrek SB - I agree with the corrections to the code, I just think some were a bit too demanding (assuming the OP is not a 50-year old C programmer). Using string instead of char* would not have solved this bug, and indexing mistakes is something that happens to experienced C++ as well.

Comment: @Eran: Seriously, I don't think it's "demanding" to ask someone to use a real, straight-forward, elegant language rather than baroque, opaque sidetracks which are unintuitive and unmaintainable -- if anything we're doing the OP a favour! Like, we are, "Don't put that fork in your eyes, you don't need the fork", and you're like, "don't be so demanding, he just started to use the fork".

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the rest of the recommendations regarding the implementation, but as for your specific problem: you `Lookup` function returns the size of dir if it doesn't find what it was looking for. Your second insert then uses that value in `contacts[idx]->Name()`, as an index. `idx` is 1, but at that point there's no value in the second cell of the array. So, when you call `Name()`, you call it on an invalid pointer. You've missed the difference between a 1-based size and a 0-based index.

In general, 0xcdcdcdcd is a common pattern, set by VS on uninitialized pointers in debug builds.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, since you are using c-style strings and the associated functions (`strlen`, etc.), you should `#include <cstring>`, not `<string>` - on my system, your code does not compile.  As vines says in the comments, you would be better off with `std::string` anyway.  To find your problem, you should run your code in a debugger as sth says.  If you still can't work out where the error is, try repeatedly removing functionality from your code and running it to narrow down the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why don't you use C++ classes for strings, such as the `std::string` lokated in `<string>`? You could avoid ugly code like this:

```
Contact::name= new char [strlen(name)+1];
Contact::address= new char [strlen(address)+1];
Contact::tell= new char [strlen(tell)+1];
strcpy(Contact::name, name);
strcpy(Contact::address, address);
strcpy(Contact::tell,tell);
```

by just typing

```
Contact::Contact(const char *name, const char *address, const char *tell) : name(name), address(address), tell(tell)
```

where these are defined in the class like this:

```
std::string name, address, tell;
```

Secondly, why do you invent the wheel again? Instead of creating your own `ContactDir` class, you could simply use the `std::map` located in `<map>`. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) is the documentation for it.

The following code instantiates a map, inserts objects and retrieves them:

```
std::map<std::string, Contact> dir;
dir["JACK"] = Contact("JACK","NORWAY", "999999"));
dir["JIMMY"] = Contact ("JIMMY","FRANCE", "313131"));

Object jimmy = dir["JIMMY"];
```

I know, I did not locate the exact spot where the segfault occurs, but I think this approach will help you more.

**EDIT:** Also I think I found your problem. In `Insert` you make a `Lookup` call, which returns, if the element was not found, the size of the dir. But in `Insert` you never check if the value was correct. I think so...